# Recreate google map in react

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

While trying to use google maps in react, dealing with an issue.

First time when the google map component gets created, it works very well.

**Problem:-** But if I visit some other page and then again go to the same Map containing page, the map is gone. It is not created again.

*Here is the component:-*

```
var React = require('react');

var MapLocation = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            map : null
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        var that = this;
        if(document.readyState !== "complete") {
            window.addEventListener("load", function () {
                that.createMap();
            })
        }
        else {
            that.createMap();
        }

    },

    createMap: function () {
        var lng = this.props.lng,
            lat = this.props.lat,
            mapCanvas = this.refs.map_canvas.getDOMNode(),
            mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(lng, lat),
                zoom: 15,
                draggable: false,
                scrollwheel: false,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lng, lat),
            map: map,
            //icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png'
        });

        this.setState({map: map});
    },

    enableScroll: function() {
        if(this.state.map) {
            this.state.map.set('scrollwheel', true);
            this.state.map.set('draggable', true);
        }
    },

    render: function () {
        var lat = this.props.lat,
            lng = this.props.lng;

        return (
            <div className='map-location'>
                <h3 className='hotel__sub-title'>
                    Location
                </h3>
                <div onClick={this.enableScroll} id="google-map" ref='map_canvas'></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

module.exports = MapLocation;
```

Comment: Seeing any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

According to [react documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount):

> void componentDidMount()
>   Invoked once, only on the client (not on the server), immediately after the initial rendering occurs.

It means that after opening other pages and returning to map page again componentDidMount will not be invoked.
I suggest you to use some google maps react modules:

- https://github.com/pieterv/react-googlemaps
- https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps

Good luck!

Comment: Same issue seems to be occuring with react-google-maps the map object dissapears when viewing second map.